# What is an alternative Linux application for Visual Basic?

Tags: programming

What is an alternative Linux application for Visual Basic?

Comment: This is going to be impossible to answer, there are opinions in many directions. You need to provide more information, your question doesn't even make coherent sense. Please specify!

Comment: ok but What is the alternative program Visual Basic

Comment: Submitted edit: Grammar, Removed Discussion starter. (Flame Bait)

Comment: This question is still too vague to answer. Please see [How to run the software-recommendation tag](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1872/how-to-run-the-software-recommendation-tag). Generally speaking though these questions are discouraged. If you're able to fix your question according to the guidelines flag for moderator attention to have it considered for re-opening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest free alternative to visual basic for Linux would be Gambas Basic. It is similar to visual basic but there is some differences, and you can't just copy and paste in VB code, if you want to see the differences you can see them at http://gambasdoc.org/help/doc/diffvb?show. Another thing that you could try is to run visual basic and the applications that you programmed in the Wine emulator under Linux.

If you are wanting to continues using Linux, just like Mfillpot said, yes you should learn python or bash.

I hope this helps.

Quoting user Mrx3000 [Source](https://www.linux.com/community/forums/system-management/alternative-for-visual-basic)

Comment: You might also check out The Linux Alternative Project @ http://www.linuxalt.com/

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question well enough, please be sure to check the Answered Button and/or +1 the answer.